# Is a wrapper the only way to test a static dependency?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, static, dependencies

I need to write a test for a class that uses a static dependency via `DllImport` and is forced into `static public extern ...`. Is there any refactoring I can do to make this testable beyond writing a wrapper around the static external dependency?

Comment: Wrapper seems to be a reasonable solution, why don't you want to use it?

Comment: I guess I was just hoping for something less clunky. Like another way to dllimport without having to be static

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use commercial mocking frameworks, like typemock, that enable mocking static methods. But in your case, I tend to agree wth Justin Pihony, that wrapping would be just fine.