# Create EventLogRecord for unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, event-log

I implemented an API to process `EventLogRecord` object.

```
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;

...
MyLog ProcessEvent(EventLogRecord eventRecord)
```

Now, I want create unit test for this and `EventLogRecord` doesn't have a public constructor. How do I get a `EventLogRecord` object without hooking up to the event logging system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of making untestable items like this (non-virtual) work is by using a wrapper. Here is some pseducode of the idea:

```
WrapperEventLogRecord : IEventLogRecordWrapper
{
    ctor(EventLogRecord eventLogRecord)
    public ActivityId {get{return _eventLogRecord.ActivityId;}}
}
```

Now you can pass in the interface and mock it out as necessary

Comment: Great! Wrapping will solve the problem. Any other options? I am a little concerned about the overhead (more code just to wrap).

Comment: If you are using a basic mocking framework, then no. See my unanswered question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203061/is-a-wrapper-the-only-way-to-test-a-static-dependency You could use a powerful mocker like TypeMock to get at the private ctor, though?